# What level of energy could an amateur particle accelerator achieve?

Tags: particle-physics, collision, elementary-particles

I am a member of a group of high schoolers and we've been looking to set our sights on a challenging project to dump some time into. Currently we're investigating how realistic it is to attempt building a small particle collider. We will likely be funded by the high school so money shouldn't be a huge issue.

Really we'll settle for just a measurable result such as photon emission from electron collisions but it'd be very nice to achieve results from proton proton collisions also. Now my question is: how realistic is this idea? Apparently proton proton collisions show decent results only in the 160+ MeV range. The current model is similar to the LHC with an accelerator loop and a collision loop.

My apologies if this question is a bit vague I will attempt to answer any questions in the replies. Thank you in advance.

Comment: By far the easiest would be a cyclotron - look at Lawrence's first one - it is pretty small. Radiation exposure is a real danger with high voltage electrons, so get real, knowledgeable help on measurement and shielding.

Comment: There is an old scientiific american project with detailed  instructions  to build a van-der Graaf accelerator.  It could produce an MeV electron beam but there were subsequent warnings that it also generated seriously hazardous amounts of X-rays.

Comment: You might also try settling with a Crooke's tube, you can accelerate electrons across the potential difference with energies depending on the voltages you can supply. X-rays are a hazard.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: relevant article https://www.scienceinschool.org/article/2014/accelerator/